# Is there a suggestion feature command for label names in TeXShop?

Tags: cross-referencing, editors, texshop, macos

In TeXShop esc or tab complete the command when you write the first letter of the command's name. I am wondering are there any commands showing similar labels name after writing the first few letter in `\eqref`. Sometimes I can not remember the labels name exactly. I think something that kind will help me.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Do you use texshop?

Comment: Yes I use TeXShop on macOS

Answer (score 7):

When typing in TeXShop, you can get a list of existing labels for various things using F5.  For example, if you have the following document, and you start typing `\eqref{` (minimally including the opening `{`), you will get a list of possible labels.  If you type more than just the opening `{` it will truncate the list using what you type as a prefix.

If you have BibDesk open with your bibliography file, you can also use this to insert citation keys from the open file (hence the "(BibDesk)" in the completion list.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{foo}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{bar}
\end{equation}

In Equation \eqref{

\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: F5 behaviour]

Comment: I didn’t know about this!!

Comment: @WillRobertson It used to work with Esc or Tab (same as command completion) but that stopped mysteriously some versions ago.  F5 is not so convenient, but it's still a nice feature.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks a lot. As far as  I remember esc did that thing a few version ago but it doesn't work now.

Comment: This reallocation of the shortcut had escaped me, too… There isn't a way to make it work for other commands like `\vref`, is there?

Comment: @Florian Unfortunately it's not possible to adjust the set of elements that trigger the completions without recompiling TeXShop itself. See [how to get TexShop to auto-complete custom citation and cross-reference commands](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/288305).

Comment: This is life-changing. Thank you